# Branch-and-price using SCIP

Tags: python, scipy, scip

I'm currently trying to implement a generic nurse rostering problem (NRP) in a branch-and-price framework in Python on Windows.

I tried using Gurobi, but apparently it isn't possible, see discussion:
https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360043240312-Branch-and-price-example

I'm searching a small example on how to set up the branch-and-price framework using SCIP in Python - to get started. I could only find examples in C and C++, which are languages I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Do you _need_ to use a branch and price approach? Modern solvers can often solve the extensive (full) form of a problem directly without needing to use iterative methods like this. Can you day more about the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I want to. One advantage is that I can determine the branching rules myself, whereas I don't know which heuristics and cutting rules are used in the different solvers.

The problem I'm trying to solve is described in this paper:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377221713002464

But I would like to add additional constraints (I haven't decided which ones yet)

Comment: My first guess is that you will not get that fine-grained control from a standard solver. You may need to write up your whole algorithm in Python or C. But you may be able to get similar results by adding columns in Python then letting the solver run to completion (its normal mode), possibly with a warm start. Or you may be able to get closer to what you want by creating a warm start that includes the new column in the basis, then run the solver with a cap on the number of iterations. I've tried that before, but haven't checked whether it deterministically pivots the new column in and one out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please have a look at [PySCIPOpt](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt), which is the Python interface of SCIP. You find in `PySCIPOpt/tests/test_pricer.py` a column-generation-based example for the cutting stock problem. Still, I would recommend looking at the [Binpacking example of SCIP](https://scip.zib.de/doc-6.0.2/html/BINPACKING_MAIN.php).

Comment: It's not the column generation approach I'm searching. It's branch-and-price, how to build the search tree and add branching rules using SCIP.

Comment: To implement your own branch-and-price algorithm, you will need to write a pricer to generate new columns and a branching rule. As I have written, an example of how to generate and add columns is shown in `test_pricer.py`. An example for writing a branching rule is shown in `test_branch_probing_lp.py`.